# command line newsreader?

Tags: newsreader, newsgroups

Does anyone out there know of a good newsreader that has a command line interface? I really like newsleecher but it is all graphical - I'd prefer to be able to script my queries.

**EDIT #1:**

As I noted above, my intent was to script my queries. So in reality anything that would automate newsgroup interaction would suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My intent was to automate my newsreader dl's. I've recently started using an app called [sickbeard](http://sickbeard.com/) to do this.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 3):

Mutt, perhaps.

Or, I bet there is a emacs plugin that does just that.

If you really want to do it hardcore, you can just throw some Python together and do one. It probably won't be that hard.

Comment: As it seems, the emacs plugin is called 'gnus'. Have a try.

Comment: I'll have to give it a go. +1

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Sickbeard + SabNZBd will do the trick.  You might also want to add in a news indexer like NewzNab.  Let me know if you need any help.